# Model not correctly training

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network

I have a custom recurrent neural network originally made (not by me) with Tensorflow/Keras that I am converting to PyTorch. I am running Python 3.12.1 and PyTorch 2.2.0. The NN has already been proven to work on Tensorflow/Keras; however, I am running into training issues with my remade version. My data is a time dependent dataset with 10000 samples, 125 time steps, and 6 (input and output) variables (tensor sizes: 10000x125x6; therefore `batch_first=True`). When I attempt to train my model, 5 of the 6 variables are modeled semi-accurately, but 1 (always the same) variable is not correct. Everything I have tried yields no difference. Below is my code:

```py
import os

os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '-1'

from pathlib import Path
import h5py
import numpy as np
import time
import pandas as pd
import torch
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
from torch import nn
from torch import optim
from torch.nn import functional as F
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import re


class H5Dataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, in_data, out_data):
        self.in_data = in_data
        self.out_data = out_data
    
    def __len__(self):
        return self.in_data.shape[0]
    
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return (self.in_data[index], self.out_data[index])


class MSC(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, hidden_size, neurons, input_size=6, output_size=6, transition_layers=1,
                 output_layers=0, use_bias=True, unit_forget_bias=True):
        super(MSC, self).__init__()
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.neurons = neurons
        self.input_size = input_size
        self.output_size = output_size
        self.transition_layers = transition_layers
        self.output_layers = output_layers
        self.use_bias = use_bias
        self.unit_forget_bias = unit_forget_bias

        self._initTransitionInternalWBs()
        self._initTransitionGatesWBs()
        self._initOutputInternalWBs()
        self._initOutputLinearWBs()
        
    def forward(self, x, X0):
        # Input Layer
        I = torch.cat((x, F.tanh(X0)), dim=-1)

        # Transition - Internal Layers
        for i in range(self.transition_layers):
            W_shape = getattr(self, f'W_I,{i}^a').shape
            W_I_a = getattr(self, f'W_I,{i}^a').reshape(1, W_shape[0], W_shape[1]).expand(I.shape[0], W_shape[0], W_shape[1])
            W_I_b = getattr(self, f'W_I,{i}^b').reshape(1, W_shape[0], W_shape[1]).expand(I.shape[0], W_shape[0], W_shape[1])

            I_alpha = torch.add(torch.bmm(I, W_I_a), getattr(self, f'b_I,{i}^a'))
            I_beta = torch.add(torch.bmm(I, W_I_b), getattr(self, f'b_I,{i}^b'))
            I = F.tanh(I_alpha)*F.tanh(I_beta)
        
        # Transition Gates
        W_i = self.W_i.reshape(1, self.W_i.shape[0], self.W_i.shape[1]).expand(I.shape[0], self.W_i.shape[0], self.W_i.shape[1])
        W_f = self.W_f.reshape(1, self.W_f.shape[0], self.W_f.shape[1]).expand(I.shape[0], self.W_f.shape[0], self.W_f.shape[1])
        W_X = self.W_X.reshape(1, self.W_X.shape[0], self.W_X.shape[1]).expand(I.shape[0], self.W_X.shape[0], self.W_X.shape[1])
        if self.use_bias:
            g_i = F.sigmoid(torch.add(torch.bmm(I, W_i), self.b_i))
            g_f = F.sigmoid(torch.add(torch.bmm(I, W_f), self.b_f))
            d_X = F.tanh(torch.add(torch.bmm(I, W_X), self.b_X))
        else:
            g_i = F.sigmoid(torch.bmm(I, W_i))
            g_f = F.sigmoid(torch.bmm(I, W_f))
            d_X = F.tanh(torch.bmm(I, W_X))
        
        # Transition - Update
        X = g_f*X0 + g_i*d_X

        # Output - Internal
        lambda_ = F.tanh(X)
        for i in range(self.output_layers):
            W_shape = getattr(self, f'W_lambda,{i}^a').shape
            W_lambda_a = getattr(self, f'W_lambda,{i}^a').reshape(1, W_shape[0], W_shape[1]).expand(lambda_.shape[0], W_shape[0], W_shape[1])
            W_lambda_b = getattr(self, f'W_lambda,{i}^b').reshape(1, W_shape[0], W_shape[1]).expand(lambda_.shape[0], W_shape[0], W_shape[1])

            lambda_alpha = torch.add(torch.bmm(lambda_, W_lambda_a), getattr(self, f'b_lambda,{i}^a'))
            lambda_beta = torch.add(torch.bmm(lambda_, W_lambda_b), getattr(self, f'b_lambda,{i}^b'))
            lambda_ = F.tanh(lambda_alpha)*F.tanh(lambda_beta)
        
        # Output - Linear
        if self.output_layers >= 0:
            W_y = self.W_y.reshape(1, self.W_y.shape[0], self.W_y.shape[1]).expand(lambda_.shape[0], self.W_y.shape[0], self.W_y.shape[1])
            y = torch.add(torch.bmm(lambda_, W_y), self.b_y)
        else:
            y = X
        return y, X
    
    def _initTransitionInternalWBs(self):
        for i in range(self.transition_layers):
            if i == 0:
                first_dim = self.hidden_size + self.input_size
            else:
                first_dim = self.neurons
            setattr(self, f'W_I,{i}^a', nn.Parameter(torch.Tensor(size=(first_dim, self.neurons))))
            setattr(self, f'b_I,{i}^a', nn.Parameter(torch.Tensor(size=[self.neurons])))
            setattr(self, f'W_I,{i}^b', nn.Parameter(torch.Tensor(size=(first_dim, self.neurons))))
            setattr(self, f'b_I,{i}^b', nn.Parameter(torch.Tensor(size=[self.neurons])))

        for name, param in self.named_parameters():
            if re.fullmatch(r'W_I,\d+\^[ab]', name) is not None:
                # he_uniform initialization
                limit = (6/self.hidden_size)**0.5
                nn.init.uniform_(param.data, -1*limit, limit)
            elif re.fullmatch(r'b_I,\d+\^a', name) is not None:
                param.data.fill_(0)
            elif re.fullmatch(r'b_I,\d+\^b', name) is not None:
                param.data.fill_(1)
    
    def _initTransitionGatesWBs(self):
        self.W_i = nn.Parameter(torch.Tensor(size=(self.neurons, self.hidden_size)))
        self.W_f = nn.Parameter(torch.Tensor(size=(self.neurons, self.hidden_size)))
        self.W_X = nn.Parameter(torch.Tensor(size=(self.neurons, self.hidden_size)))
        
        if self.use_bias:
            self.b_i = nn.Parameter(torch.Tensor(size=[self.hidden_size]))
            self.b_f = nn.Parameter(torch.Tensor(size=[self.hidden_size]))
            self.b_X = nn.Parameter(torch.Tensor(size=[self.hidden_size]))

        for name, param in self.named_parameters():
            if name == 'W_i' or name == 'W_f' or name == 'W_X':
                # he_uniform initialization
                limit = (6/self.hidden_size)**0.5
                nn.init.uniform_(param.data, -1*limit, limit)
            if self.use_bias:
                if name == 'b_i' or name == 'b_X':
                    param.data.fill_(0)
                elif name == 'b_f':
                    if self.unit_forget_bias:
                        param.data.fill_(1)
                    else:
                        param.data.fill_(0)
    
    def _initOutputInternalWBs(self):
        for i in range(self.output_layers):
            if i == 0:
                first_dim = self.hidden_size
            else:
                first_dim = self.neurons
            setattr(self, f'W_lambda,{i}^a', nn.Parameter(torch.Tensor(size=(first_dim, self.neurons))))
            setattr(self, f'b_lambda,{i}^a', nn.Parameter(torch.Tensor(size=[self.neurons])))
            setattr(self, f'W_lambda,{i}^b', nn.Parameter(torch.Tensor(size=(first_dim, self.neurons))))
            setattr(self, f'b_lambda,{i}^b', nn.Parameter(torch.Tensor(size=[self.neurons])))

        for name, param in self.named_parameters():
            if re.fullmatch(r'W_lambda,\d+\^[ab]', name) is not None:
                # he_uniform initialization
                limit = (6/self.hidden_size)**0.5
                nn.init.uniform_(param.data, -1*limit, limit)
            elif re.fullmatch(r'b_lambda,\d+\^a', name) is not None:
                param.data.fill_(0)
            elif re.fullmatch(r'b_lambda,\d+\^b', name) is not None:
                param.data.fill_(1)
    
    def _initOutputLinearWBs(self):
        if self.output_layers <= 0:
            end_dim = self.hidden_size
        else:
            end_dim = self.neurons
        
        self.W_y = nn.Parameter(torch.Tensor(size=(end_dim, self.output_size)))
        self.b_y = nn.Parameter(torch.Tensor(size=[self.output_size]))

        for name, param in self.named_parameters():
            if name == 'W_y':
                # he_uniform initialization
                limit = (6/self.hidden_size)**0.5
                nn.init.uniform_(param.data, -1*limit, limit)
            elif name == 'b_y':
                param.data.fill_(0)


def readData(file):
    f = h5py.File(file, 'r')
    inputs = np.swapaxes(np.array(f['series']['input']), 0, 2)
    outputs = np.swapaxes(np.array(f['series']['output']), 0, 2)
    inputs = torch.from_numpy(inputs)
    outputs = torch.from_numpy(outputs)
    return inputs, outputs


def createDataLoader(inputs,outputs,device,batch):
    dataset = H5Dataset(inputs, outputs)
    if str(device) == 'cuda':
        data_loader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=batch, shuffle=True, pin_memory=True, pin_memory_device=str(device))
    else:
        data_loader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=batch, shuffle=True, pin_memory=True)
    return data_loader


def plotLoss(epoch,loss):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
    ax.plot(list(range(epoch + 1)), loss, 'k-', label='Training')
    ax.set_xlabel('Epoch', fontsize=18)
    ax.set_ylabel('MSE Loss', fontsize=18)
    ax.set_xlim(left=0.0)
    ax.set_ylim(bottom=0.0)
    ax.grid(True)
    ax.legend()
    fig.set_size_inches(8, 6)
    fig.suptitle('Train All Outputs')
    plot_file = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent / 'output' / 'Training_Loss.png'
    plt.savefig(plot_file, dpi=200)
    plt.close()
    return


def train(model,optimizer,epochs,batch,seq_len,train_loader,hidden_size,device,loss_func,clip):
    t1 = time.time()
    model.train()
    loss_vals = []
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        state = torch.zeros(batch, seq_len, hidden_size, dtype=torch.float64).to(device)
        for i, (inputs, targets) in enumerate(train_loader):
            out, state = model(inputs[:, :seq_len, :], state)
            loss = loss_func(out, targets[:, :seq_len, :])

            loss.backward()
            nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), clip)
            optimizer.step()
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            state = state.detach()

        with torch.no_grad():
            dt = time.time() - t1
            t_remain = (epochs - (epoch+1))*dt/(epoch+1)
            lr_val = optimizer.param_groups[0]['lr']
            print(f'Time elapsed: {dt/60.0:.2f} min')
            print(f'Epoch {epoch + 1}/{epochs} | Loss {loss.item():.6f} | LR {lr_val}')
            print(f'Estimated time remaining: {t_remain/60.0:.2f} min\n\n')
            loss_vals.append(loss.item())
            plotLoss(epoch,loss_vals)
    return


def plotEval(eval_data,model_data,output_dir):
    y_titles = ['Output 1', 'Output 2', 'Output 3', 'Output 4', 'Output 5', 'Output 6']
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 3, figsize=(18, 9), tight_layout=True)
    for i in range(6):
        r = int(i/3)
        c = i%3
        MSE = nn.MSELoss()(model_data[1, :, i], eval_data[1, :, i])
        ax[r, c].plot(list(range(eval_data.shape[1])), eval_data[1, :, i], 'k-', label='Data')
        ax[r, c].plot(list(range(model_data.shape[1])), model_data[1, :, i].detach(), 'r-', label='Model')
        ax[r, c].text(0.5, 0.95, f'MSE: {MSE}', fontsize=10)
        ax[r, c].set_ylabel(y_titles[i])
        ax[r, c].set_xlabel('Time Steps')
        ax[r, c].set_xlim(left=0.0)
        ax[r, c].grid(True)
        if i == 0:
            ax[r, c].legend()
    fig.suptitle('Train All Outputs; Model Fit')
    plt.savefig(output_dir / f'Model_Fit_Evaluation.png', dpi=200)
    plt.close()
    return


def evaluate(model,batch,seq_len,data_loader,hidden_size,device,loss_func,output_dir=None):
    model.eval()
    state = torch.zeros(batch, seq_len, hidden_size, dtype=torch.float64).to(device)
    for i, (inputs, targets) in enumerate(data_loader):
            out, state = model(inputs[:, :seq_len, :], state)
            loss = loss_func(out, targets[:, :seq_len, :])

            if i == 0:
                outputs = targets[:, :seq_len, :]
                model_outputs = out
            else:
                outputs = torch.cat((outputs, targets[:, :seq_len, :]), 0)
                model_outputs = torch.cat((model_outputs, out), 0)

    if output_dir is not None:
        plotEval(outputs,model_outputs,output_dir)
    return loss.item()


def main(train_data,val_data,hidden_size,layers,neurons,data_dir=Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent / 'input',
         batch=64,n_tot=125,in_size=6,out_size=6,out_layers=0,epochs=2500,clip=1e-2,lr=5e-3):
    output_dir = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent / 'output'
    device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')

    # load training and validation data
    train_file = data_dir / f'{train_data}.h5'
    train_inputs, train_outputs = readData(train_file)
    val_file = data_dir / f'{val_data}.h5'
    val_inputs, val_outputs = readData(val_file)
    
    # create data loaders
    train_loader = createDataLoader(train_inputs,train_outputs,device,batch)
    val_loader = createDataLoader(val_inputs,val_outputs,device,batch)

    # Define model, optimizer, and loss
    model_name  = f'{train_data}_MSC_u{hidden_size}_w{neurons}_d{layers}_od{out_layers}_n{n_tot}'
    model = MSC(hidden_size, neurons, input_size=in_size, output_size=out_size, transition_layers=layers, output_layers=out_layers).to(device)
    optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=lr)
    loss_func = nn.MSELoss()

    t_start = time.time()
    train(model,optimizer,epochs,batch,n_tot,train_loader,hidden_size,device,loss_func,clip)
    t_tot = time.time() - t_start
    
    # save model
    ckpt_file = output_dir / f'{model_name}.json'
    model_dict = {'model_state_dict':model.state_dict(), 'optimizer_state_dict':optimizer.state_dict()}
    torch.save(model_dict, ckpt_file)

    # evaluate 
    eval_train = evaluate(model,batch,n_tot,train_loader,hidden_size,device,loss_func)
    eval_valid = evaluate(model,batch,n_tot,val_loader,hidden_size,device,loss_func,output_dir)
    
    data = [hidden_size, neurons, layers, out_layers, n_tot, epochs, t_tot, eval_train, eval_valid]
    columns = ['Hidden Size', 'Neurons', 'Transition Layers', 'Output Layers', 'Increments', 'Total Epochs', 'Total Time (s)', 'MSE Training', 'MSE Validation']
    df = pd.DataFrame([data], columns=columns)
    print(df)
    df.to_json(output_dir / f'{model_name}_results.json', orient='index', indent=2)
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    torch.set_default_dtype(torch.float64)
    torch.random.manual_seed(0)

    train_data_name = 'NN_VM3D_D2'
    val_data_name = f'{train_data_name}v'
    units = 7
    depth = 4
    width = 25
    batch_size = 100
    out_depth = 0
    num_epochs = 500
    main(train_data_name,val_data_name,units,depth,width,batch=batch_size,out_layers=out_depth,epochs=num_epochs,in_size=1,out_size=1)
```

Here are the results and plots of the loss and model fit for typical run where the problem can be seen.

```json
{
  "0":{
    "Hidden Size":7,
    "Neurons":25,
    "Transition Layers":4,
    "Output Layers":0,
    "Increments":125,
    "Total Epochs":500,
    "Total Time (s)":1166.4787528515,
    "MSE Training":0.0814923346,
    "MSE Validation":0.0802977346
  }
}
```

[image: Loss for Training All Outputs]
[image: Model Fit for Training All Outputs]

Here are the results and plots of the loss and model fit if the singular problem variable is excluded from training (therefore input and output tensors are 10000x125x5).

```json
{
  "0":{
    "Hidden Size":7,
    "Neurons":25,
    "Transition Layers":4,
    "Output Layers":0,
    "Increments":125,
    "Total Epochs":500,
    "Total Time (s)":1162.5445659161,
    "MSE Training":0.0208534161,
    "MSE Validation":0.019900983
  }
}
```

[image: Loss for Training Outputs 2-6 Only]
[image: Model Fit for Training Outputs 2-6 Only]

Here are the results and plots of the loss and model fit if the singular problem variable is the only variable included in training (therefore input and output tensors are 10000x125x1).

```json
{
  "0":{
    "Hidden Size":7,
    "Neurons":25,
    "Transition Layers":4,
    "Output Layers":0,
    "Increments":125,
    "Total Epochs":500,
    "Total Time (s)":1136.6203773022,
    "MSE Training":0.4494353248,
    "MSE Validation":0.4549513415
  }
}
```

[image: Loss for Training Output 1 Only]
[image: Model Fit for Training Output 1 Only]